# Is there a way in wordpress for setting the default template file to a custom one?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way in wordpress for setting the default template file(index.php) to a custom one?

Thank you.

Comment: make duplicate `index.php` and rename it as 'page-id.php' example: `page-1.php`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about WordPress theme design and belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about wordpress, it should belong on the wordpress site.

Comment: This question appears to be specifically Wordpress related. Try wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a file called "page.php" and put in default theme directory.

This will override index.php AND be the default used template (you can still change template using the dropdown list in the back end)

check here for more info:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/